# Ubuntu ppc64el performance

Tags: ibm, ppc64le

I installed Ubuntu Linux 14.04.5 on a new IBM Power8 mod. 8286-41a.
My goal is to use this partition the application SugarCRM CE 6.5. 
I’m not been able to install ubuntu 16 because compatibility issues with PHP 5.6.
Currently i use sugarcrm on a vmware virtual machine with  ubuntu 14.4.1.
I was expecting a performance boost on ppc64el platform.
Instead I've found, in fact the procedures are considerably slower than the amd64 machine 
Same lamp version on both system (apache 2.4.7, mysql 5.6.33, php 5.5.9)
See attached image for information on the two machines. 
Any suggestions?
[ppc64el vs amd64 config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfEZB.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: You just happen to be using versions of everything that are before a lot of ppc64el and POWER8 optimizations went in, so there's going to be limits on what performance you can achieve without upgrading one (or more) components.

Around the time Ubuntu 14.04 was released, we went through the whole LAMP stack looking closely at performance on POWER. We found that there were places that were lacking, so we went to work fixing them. Unfortunately, since Ubuntu 14.04 shipped slightly before the first POWER8 systems did, there wasn't enough time to work on the optimizations and get them into upstream before Ubuntu 14.04 shipped.

It was only in May/June 2014 that I had an initial (relatively) stable patchset for MySQL 5.6 working on POWER8. This was a couple of months after Ubuntu 14.04 release. These initial patches weren't too focused on performance (although Ubuntu did pull them in to the distro, as ppc64el is a supported platform for them).

For performance, we were pretty heavily gated on a few things, many of which were being fixed in MySQL 5.7. I had a very proof-of-concept MySQL 5.7 port doing 1 million queries/second on POWER8 back in June 2014. A lot of the MySQL problems are around mutex contention, so it can (strangely enough) with older MySQL *improve* performance by tying MySQL to fewer CPU cores.

We had other bottlenecks to tackle too, notably CRC32 performance (which if you configure it to do so, InnoDB uses as its on disk checksum), of which emerged a POWER8 optimized CRC32 that is **41 times faster** than the non-optimized version. This work was integrated with MariaDB 10.1.

A lot of work was done to get modern MariaDB running really well on POWER8. It does, so if switching to MariaDB is an option, that will help with database end performance. Also, the various _instance variables for MySQL may need increasing - your POWER8 system likely has a *lot* more CPU cores and threads than an x86 system, and the default values aren't going to be that great.

As for PHP, I was a (lot) less involved in that optimization work. Basically, newer PHP is faster, often by a decent amount. This was due to everything from removing some old powerpc "optimizations" (custom assembly isn't always faster than what a compiler can produce) to contributing code to php, to (i think) improving GCC.

I think my colleague Daniel Axtens is going to reply with some of the PHP details.

Back to your specific configuration, have you assigned 1 CPU core (with 8 threads) or just 1 CPU core (with 1 thread) to the VM on the POWER8? The way virtualization works on POWER, you may as well give the guest the threads, as a the whole core enters the guest at the same time, and SMT4 is usually a big boost for performance over SMT1 (check your VM configuration and you can dynamically change the thread mode using the ppc64_cpu utility in the guest, but not to more threads than the guest has been assigned).

I blogged a bunch on the POWER8 MySQL/MariaDB work over at: https://www.flamingspork.com/blog (see the mysql/power8 tags... askubuntu won't let me post too many links)

Comment: many thanks to all for the information. I wanted to give some more info on my project. The P8 server has a process and 6 cores available. One core is dedicated to IBMi partitions, while the other wanted to use them to the linux world by running two separate instances of SugarCRM. I am currently testing a partition to which I assigned a process units.

Comment: I tryed ppc64_cpu util:
$ ppc64_cpu --cores-present
Number of cores present = 1
-- $ ppc64_cpu --cores-on
Number of cores online = 1
-- $ ppc64_cpu --threads-per-core
Threads per core: 8
-- $ ppc64_cpu --smt
SMT=8
-- $ ppc64_cpu --info
Core   0:    0*    1*    2*    3*    4*    5*    6*    7*
Any suggestion ?

Comment: You probably want to use the PowerVM management tools to assign the LPAR statically. I'm not 100% sure what this is called. Then you should also try SMT-4. I'm not sure if you can do this in PowerVM or if you need to use ppc64_cpu inside the partition.

Comment: @bob3321, in fact, if you can't find this PowerVM info on the web, please ask a question on serverfault (and link it here and tag me in) - otherwise all the questions and answers will get hidden in these comments rather than out where people can find them.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty difficult to answer as asked - it would be really helpful to know what parts are slower, how you're measuring speed, etc.

But here are a few pointers:

Firstly, **you need to move to 16.04**.

- You've said you do that because of PHP issues. I assume by that you mean that SugarCRM relies on PHP5 and 16.04 only ships with PHP7. This is a shame: php7 is *much* faster than php5 (around 2x, most of the time) on both Intel and Power. But that's not the end of the world. You could move to 16.04 and use HHVM, which is compatible with PHP5 and is usually a lot faster. There's been a lot of great work getting that to work well on Power (some of which I've been involved in). I think most of the work is now upstream, but there's a [development repo](https://github.com/PPC64/hhvm) that should be even more up to date. You'll have to compile it from source, but the instructions are good.
- You really, really need to get an upgraded MySQL/MariaDB, both from a stability and performance point of view. Whatever is shipped with 14.04 is a *bad idea*.
- As Stewart mentioned, there are a *lot* of fixes that went in between 14.04 and 16.04. These chips are different to Intel chips: tuning applications for them is different and relies on work we have been doing over a few years. These fixes range from kernel fixes to power scaling to compiler improvements to generate better code.

Secondly, I'm not sure what workload you're testing on SugarCRM. IBM has a (now somewhat dated) [white paper](https://www-356.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/stg_ast_sys_wp_power-systems-solutions-sugar-crm) on running SugarCRM on Power that shows it sustaining much greater throughput than an Intel system. **You need to be clear on the benchmark you're interested in.**

Thirdly, **you need to check your system settings**. Here are some common ones:

- Apache not set to use pthread mutexes instead of file mutexes (fixed in newer Ubuntu versions)
- PHP and Apache set to use a thread pool that is too small for a Power system.
- It looks like you're comparing 1 core on P8 to 4 cores on x86. P8 has both cores and hardware threads (like HyperThreading but instead of 2 hardware threads per core we have up to 8), so this can get a bit confusing. You should:

  - give you Power VM 4 cores. If possible, make sure they're statically allocated in your hypervisor (as in, the cores are dedicated to the guest).
  - Set those 4 cores to SMT-4 mode, not SMT-8 mode; this tends to give a considerable boost to scripting languages.

Lastly, if you have access to any IBM support or sales people from when you bought the machine, please reach out to them; they may be able to get some experts in.

Comment: Regarding HHVM, we have deb files in a repository for Ubuntu, so, you don't need to compile from source. Please check https://launchpad.net/~ibmpackages/+archive/ubuntu/hhvm

Comment: Thank you very much for information.To test the performance I only considered the time required to carry out some data exchange procedures between IBMi and sugarcrm.
These procedures use jdbc driver. I also checked out some php script (scheduling sugarcrm) are slower.

Comment: in the coming weeks I try to install ubuntu 16.04 with HHVM instead of PHP.
Meanwhile, where I can find some more info about your recommended  system setting? I'm not expert in apache configuration and CPU configuration. Thank you

Comment: You are likely to find that single-threaded PHP is a bit slower. But, Power will pull ahead when you move to multi-threaded operations - you will be able to support more users per machine using a Power system. 

I don't know anything about IBM i or JDBC, so I'll let others help there.

I don't have a good reference for tuning on hand but I will ask some IBM experts for some links. Are you using PowerVM or PowerKVM?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing performance measurements, create the partition from the HMC using dedicated processors, with 4 cores as the desired (by using dedicated, you will be separating the IBM i workload from this test workload). As mentioned before, thread count is different from Power than from x86, so you have to make sure you have the right amount of cores, not threads (even setting SMT-4 as recommended, you will still have twice the amount of threads per core on Power).

Comment: thank for info. i'm using IVM for partiotion manager. When i created ubuntu partition i choose "1 Assigned processor" and "Dedicated" as processing mode. How do I configure Ubuntu to use 4 cores in SMT-4 mode?